# Welch's procedure proof

Tags: probability, simulation

In Welch's procedure, how does $E(\bar{Y}_i)=E(Y_i)$ and $V(\bar{Y}_i)=V(Y_i)/n$.
I do not understand how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `simulation` tag, it seems you're interested in the so-called  [Welch's procedure](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~n2ddg/IE419/43.htm) that uses a variance-reduction method applied to $n$ independent "replicates" of a time series $Y_1,...,Y_m$.   (Each replicate is supposed to have the same distribution as the time series; e.g., if $Y_{ji}$ is the $i$th observation in the $j$th replicate, then for all $j$, $Y_{ji}$ has the same distribution as $Y_i$.)   Letting $\overline{Y_i}$ be the arithmetic mean of the $i$th observation across the $n$ replicates:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\overline{Y_i})
~=~& \mathsf E(\frac{1}{n}~\sum_{j=1}^n Y_{ji}) 
\\[1ex] =~& \frac{1}{n}~\mathsf E(\sum_{j=1}^n Y_{ji})
\\[1ex] =~&\frac{1}{n}~\sum_{j=1}^n \mathsf E(Y_{ji})
\\[1ex] =~&\frac{1}{n}~\sum_{j=1}^n \mathsf E(Y_{i})
\\[1ex] =~&\frac{1}{n}~n~\mathsf E(Y_{i})
\\[1ex] =~& \mathsf E(Y_{i})
\\[3ex]\mathsf V(\overline{Y_i})
~=~& \mathsf V(\frac{1}{n}~\sum_{j=1}^n Y_{ji})
\\[1ex] =~&\frac{1}{n^2}~\mathsf V(\sum_{j=1}^n Y_{ji})
\\[1ex] =~&\frac{1}{n^2}~\sum_{j=1}^n \mathsf V(Y_{ji})
\\[1ex] =~&\frac{1}{n^2}~\sum_{j=1}^n \mathsf V(Y_{i})
\\[1ex] =~&\frac{1}{n^2}~n~\mathsf V(Y_{i})
\\[1ex] =~&\frac{1}{n}~\mathsf V(Y_{i})
\end{align}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp - Thanks for prettifying the MathJax.